# Android executes task sequentially or not?

Tags: android, android-activity, call, callstack

I am getting a very interesting behavior by Android Studio in my project. The calls to different activities are not executing sequentially!

I am building a project where in the calls are like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener()
{
    (1) call to cusom camera acivity
    (2) call to activity showing preview of latest captured image         
    (3) call to a doCrop() function
}
```

But when executed, the actual flow is:

```
    (1) call to the doCrop() function
    (2) call to activity showing preview of image captured
    (3) call to cusom camera acivity
```

The custom camera activity handles all the necessary `SurfaceHolder` and `SurfaceView` operations.

Is this effect happening as the `SurfaceView` layout creation and destroying takes more time and android switches to easier one task first?

Even so, it should skip to `preview activity` and not to `doCrop()` call.

What is happening here? Please give some pointers !

Thank you!

EDIT:

The naming is:

`MainActivity` - main activity

`Preview` - creates camera instance

`CameraPreview` - Handles SurfaceView etc

`ImagePreview` -Shows specified image

`Main activity` code:

```
photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                File temp = new File(//path to store image);
                imageUri=Uri.fromFile(temp);

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Preview.class);

                startActivity(intent);

               // Image Preview Activity
                Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImagePreview.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

                //Crop function
                doCrop();

            }

        });
```

The `preview activity` code:

```
public class Preview extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CamTestActivity";
    CameraPreview preview;
    Button buttonClick;
    Camera camera;
    Activity act;
    Context ctx;
    Uri uri;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;
        act = this;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

        preview = new CameraPreview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
        preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(preview);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, pngCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if(numCams > 0){
            try{
                camera = Camera.open(0);
                camera.startPreview();
                preview.setCamera(camera);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex){
                Toast.makeText(ctx, getString(R.string.camera_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            preview.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void resetCam() {
        camera.startPreview();
        preview.setCamera(camera);
    }

    private void refreshGallery(File file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {

        }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        }
    };

    PictureCallback pngCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
            resetCam();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - png");
        }
    };

    private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
              // save the image
            }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`CameraPreview` code:

```
class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;

    CameraPreview(Context context, SurfaceView sv) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = sv;

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();

            // get Camera parameters
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                // set the focus mode
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

                // set Camera parameters
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;
        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if(mCamera != null) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post your code here if possible

Comment: @vaishnavee, see my answer please, and accept it if appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more of a design issue.
Should you really be opening more than one activity at once?

When an activity is started, it's put on top of the history stack, which could give the illusion that it's happening the other way round.

But I can't comment any further until I see code.

UPDATE: Yep, design issue.

This is the way it should work:

1. Onclick action in MainActivity should ONLY open Preview activity using startActivityForResult().
2. User takes photo, triggering setResult() and closing the camera activity.
3. Result gets returned to MainActivity, triggering onActivityResult()
4. Code in onActivityResult starts ImagePreview activity.
5. onCreate function in ImagePreview triggers doCrop();

I do suggest you have a good read of the Android Documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Android is less flexible (or more helpful) than other platforms and it's essential that you have a good understanding of the API.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes, my project needs the above flow. I have updated the post with code

Comment: Very confusing, you should only ever need to call startActivity once. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

You need to run the camera activity, return result and show the taken image?

Comment: I think someone isn't reading the documentation ;-) See update above.

Answer (score 1):

Activity startup code is asynchronous, and if you launch several activities simultaneously, like this:

```
startActivity(intent1);
startActivity(intent2);
startActivity(intent3);
```

it is not guaranteed, that they'll be shown to user sequentially, that is, in "launch order".

This is expected behaviour, and you normally should not do such a thing, as it is indication of your application design flaw

Comment: Thanx for the reply. So how can i achieve the required flow?

Comment: @micwallace's answer provides good point on how to achieve it - make a flow where Activity is started to handle one action and give result to another activity. One job at a time

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to do is launch 3 activities simultaneously.These all need to be handled in `onActivityResult()`. But a user cannot access 3 activities simultaneously. 
so modifying your flow.
it should be something like

1. start CameraActivity
2. In the `onActivityResult()` of your calling activity ,you call do crop and do what you want.

You need to revisit your workflow because:

1. you are not launching 3 activites.
2. you are triggerring events based on user interaction and hence the sequence of functions should not be controlled from your code.

Comment: I tried to start the camera activity with `onResult()` but it does not return back to the parent activity (MainActivity). Please see my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393694/releasing-camera-instance-after-a-single-image-is-captured-and-returning-to-pare)

Comment: @vaishnavee why do you need a custom camera activity though?are you also doing anything there?can you not use a camera launch intent?

Comment: I want to launch the camera in different settings, like different scene mode and brightness etc . With camera intent we can't manipulate these settings, can we?

Answer (score 1):

Your tasks are executing in wrong order because they are called **asynchronously**. To execute them in the order you have specified make a **synchronous** call, which can be done using `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);`

Comment: Thnx for the reply, please see my question here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393694/releasing-camera-instance-after-a-single-image-is-captured-and-returning-to-pare). I tried to get the camera activity to return back but couldn't.